# How does Flink decide when to take a checkpoint?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'd like to understand what determines when checkpoints are taken. How does this relate to the checkpointing interval?

Answer (score 5):

To a first approximation, the Checkpoint Coordinator (part of the Job Manager) uses the checkpoint interval to determine when to start a new checkpoint. This interval is passed when you enable checkpointing, e.g., here is it set wait for 10 seconds between checkpoints:

```
env.enableCheckpointing(10000L);
```

or it can also be set via `execution.checkpointing.interval`.

However, the Checkpoint Coordinator will wait however long is necessary to avoid violating either the setting for `execution.checkpointing.max-concurrent-checkpoints` or for `execution.checkpointing.min-pause` (which defines how much time must elapse between the completion of one checkpoint and the start of the next one).